# Prove the projection map $T$ onto a subspace is linear, satisfies $T^2 = T$, and $\operatorname{range}(I - T) = \operatorname{null} T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$ satisfying $V = U \oplus W$. Prove that
>   $$T : V = U\oplus W  \to U : v = u + w \mapsto u$$
>   is a linear map that satisfies $T^2=T$ and $\operatorname{range}(I−T) = \operatorname{null}T.$

I have already used the method of direct sum and rank-nullity theorem, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

$T(u+w)=u=u+0$ so $T(T(u+w))=T(u+0)=u=T(u+w)$ so $T^{2}=T$.

$T(u+w)=0$ iff $u=0$ iff $u+w \in W$ iff $u+w \in (I-T)(V)$ since $(I-T)(V)=\{(u+w)-u=w: u \in U, w \in W\}=W$.